# Selenium partially prints elements texts found and prints null for rest of the elements text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm creating a webscraper for Target.com for a personal project and have gotten through most of it until this part, this is the code that I'm stuck on.

```
vinyls = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-test='list-entry-product-card']")

for x in vinyls:

    print(x.get_attribute('innerText') + '\n')
```

It prints the correct output for 3 or 4 of the elements, but then it goes through iterations for the rest of the elements with no text output.
Ex:
**
Olivia Rodrigo - SOUR (Target Exclusive, Vinyl)
Universal Music Group
Only at
target
¬
4.6 out of 5 stars with 258 ratings
258
$24.99
Free standard shipping with $35 orders
Not at Plano
Check nearby stores
Add for shipping
**

And then two other outputs similar to the first one followed by around 20 null outputs. The odd thing is that it will show that the nodes are there, just no text.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you wait for all elements to be there? Try adding webdriver waits.

Comment: I don't see any text as _Olivia Rodrigo - SOUR (Target Exclusive, Vinyl)_ on https://www.target.com/, am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the elements you can't get their texts are out of the visible screen viewport.
In order to get their texts properly you will have to scroll to the elements, get these elements again and then extract their texts.
Something like this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-test='list-entry-product-card']")))
time.sleep(0.5)

vinyls = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-test='list-entry-product-card']")
for idx, vinyl in enumerate(vinyls):
    actions.move_to_element(vinyls[idx]).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    vinyls = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-test='list-entry-product-card']")
    print(vinyls[idx].get_attribute('innerText') + '\n')
```

You will need these import:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
```